# verbatim environment in beamer with polyglossia

Tags: beamer, polyglossia, obeylines

it seems `verbatim` and `obeylines` do not work straight forward in `beamer` like in `article` `\DocumentClass`. It needs the [fragile] option for the frames using it.

Here I put my MWE in which I used successfully `verbatim` for latin script. It does not work with foreign script used with polyglossia, it causes a crash. `obeylines` does not cause any crash and work only partially. It does not reproduce any blank line.

So could anyone provide a solution to get a `obeylines` like environment in the case where foreign script is used and in beamer?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newcommand{\sam}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{title}
  \begin{english}
  \begin{verbatim}
Adipisci fuga et quis dicta
est et odit. Illo aut nulla
qui incidunt necessitatibus
nulla qui.

Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi
quam commodi culpa quaerat
  \end{verbatim}
  \end{english}
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{ढ़}
  \begin{obeylines}
लोकनितं मम करणीयम्

मनसा सततं स्मरणीयम्
वचसा सततं वदनीयम्
लोकहितं मम करणीयम् ॥ लोकहितम् ॥
  \end{obeylines}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you just create a tag named "obeylines"?

Comment: yes, it seems there was no tag `obeylines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verbatim` works fine as long as your typewriter font has the necessary glyphs:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newcommand{\sam}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifonttt{NotoSansDevanagari}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{\foreignlanguage{english}{title}}
  \begin{english}
  \begin{verbatim}
Adipisci fuga et quis dicta
est et odit. Illo aut nulla
qui incidunt necessitatibus
nulla qui.

Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi
quam commodi culpa quaerat
  \end{verbatim}
  \end{english}
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{ढ़}
  \begin{verbatim}
लोकनितं मम करणीयम्

मनसा सततं स्मरणीयम्
वचसा सततं वदनीयम्
लोकहितं मम करणीयम् ॥ लोकहितम् ॥
  \end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: from the error message it seemed lualatex lost its way to the font by entering into the `verbatim` environment. But I think you have to explain furthermore.

Comment: @user1850133 lualatex did not lose anything, you just did not define a typewriter font which supports your characters. The default typewriter font does not have these characters.

Comment: your answers raises one question in my mind. Actually, you solution tells that in a `verbatim` environment the Mono font is used. This is probably what I would expect as introduction in your answer. Therefore, I'm asking... why so? is it a bug? Why is it not mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @user1850133 Why should a verbatim environment not use typewriter font? That's the natural choice for setting source code, which is the main application area for verbatim environments.

Comment: @user1850133 You shouldn't change the scope of your question after you've gotten an answer.  Ask a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: @user1850133 "Why is it not mentioned in the docs? " ... the doc for the verbatim environment literally starts with telling you which font it will use https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yLrh.png

Comment: `typewriter` is not an easy word for today's citizens that's why i did not find your answer clear.

Comment: As for the use of `<language>fonttt{...}`, it does not work for me. Only `\setmonofont{...}` works, for `english`. If i do not use `\setmonofont{...}` whatever setting of `englishfonttt{...}` makes lualatex being stuck with `FiraMono`. Try your code with `metropolis` layout.

Comment: ok for the docs.